# When I try to use smtplib to send emails, I get an error

Tags: python, email, smtplib

```python
from email import message
import smtplib
sender_email = "example@gmail.com"
rec_email = "example@gmail.com"

password = "example"
message1 = "test"

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

server.starttls

server.login(sender_email, password)
server.sendmail(sender_email, rec_email, message)
```

when I do this I get the error

`smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.`

Does anyone know a solution to this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224073/smtp-auth-extension-not-supported-by-server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224073/smtp-auth-extension-not-supported-by-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try 456 port instead

```
import smtplib

sender_email = "sender_email@example.com" 
rec_email = "rec_email@example.com"
password = "password" 
message1 = "test" 
    

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login(sender_email, password)
server.sendmail(sender_email, rec_email, message1)
server.quit()
```