SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server. - SMTPlib Gmail
I am getting error:
SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
When running the blow code:
import smtplib

sender_email = 'MyRealGmail'
password = 'mypassword'
receiver_email = 'testemail'
subject = 'List'
body = 'test body'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls
server.login(sender_email, password)
print("login success")
server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, body)
print("email has been sent")

I cant seem to get this to work.

It seems you have to connect first (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37224235/18160754)
